# Programs that Find Numbers Divisible by 5 or 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, mathematical-optimization

i want to make a program to find how many number is divisible by 3 or 5 in a number for example 10 has 3 9 6 divisible by 3 and has 5 and 10 divisible by 5 so total is 5 and so on so i write my code

```
import math
n=float(raw_input())
div3=(n-2)/3
div5=(n-4)/5
f1=math.ceil(div3)
f2=math.ceil(div5)
sumss=f1+f2
print int(sumss)
```

but in some number it get wrong answer and the range of input number will be 
from 1 to 10^18 so i need to use math in it because the time limit for the problem test is 2 second any one have any efficiently equation to make that the loop cant make it it take very long time

Comment: This is project Euler? Mind that some divisors are shared between `5` and `3`

Comment: so what i will do to solve this more to be clear input 20 will output 9 and input 9 output 4

Comment: Sorry but, I dont think you have got the logic correctly here.

Comment: @Radan: well by using floating point numbers, you make the problem harder since the mantissa cannot represent numbers correctly with 9 numbers precision (in general), by using `int`, you're probably safer.

Comment: @Radan: indeed: project Euler asks to *sum up* the multiples.

Comment: Thanks. question is bit confusion at that part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a project Euler question. The issue is that some numbers can be shared by `3` and `5`. For instance `22`:

divisors of `3`: `3` `6`, `9`, `12`, **`15`**, `18`, `21`.

divisors of `5`: `5` `10`, **`15`**, `20`

For both `15` occurs, so you did a double count.

The advantage is that `3` and `5` are relatively prime, so the only numbers that are shared are the ones dividable by `15`. So you simply need to undo the double counting:

```
n=int(raw_input())
div3=n//3
div5=n//5
div15=n//15
sumss=div3+div5-div15
print sumss
```

In case you **allow double counting** (`15` should be counted twice), you can simply use:

```
n=int(raw_input())
div3=n//3
div5=n//5
sumss=div3+div5
print sumss
```

Note that the programs omitted the floating point arithmetic: this will result in both faster and more precise programs since floating point numbers work with a limited mantisse and thus can fail to represent a large number correctly (resulting by small errors). Furthermore in general integer arithmetic is faster.

## Project Euler #1

Now the problem statement of Project Euler is a bit different: it asks to **sum up** these numbers. In order to do that, you have to construct an expression to sum up the first *k* multiples of *l*:

```
 k
---
\
/     l*i
---
i=1
```

Using *Wolfram Alpha*, one gets [this expression](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20of%20l*i%20with%20i%20from%201%20to%20k). So you can calculate these as:

```
def suml (k,l) :
    return k*(k+1)*l/2

n=int(raw_input())
div3=n//3
div5=n//5
div15=n//15
sumss=suml(div3,3)+suml(div5,5)-suml(div15,15)
print sumss
```

This program gives `119` for `n=22` which - you can verify above - is correct if you count `15` only once.

Comment: fantaaaaaaaastic you are genius thank you code Accepted second one

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I got the question right, but here is some idea:

```
n=float(raw_input())
div3=int(n/3)
div5=int(n/5)
div15=int(n/15)
sumss=div3+div5-div15
print sumss
```

EDIT: Ah, found the project Euler.

> If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or
>   5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. The sum of these multiples is 23.
>
> Find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000.

That is a different task then the question posted here. It says **bellow** the number and to **find the sum**.

*I am not sure whether it would be the right thing to post the solution here, so I am rather not doing that.*

EDIT2: from Project Euler:

> We hope that you enjoyed solving this problem. Please do not deprive
>   others of going through the same process by publishing your solution
>   outside Project Euler. If you want to share your insights then please
>   go to thread 1 in the discussion forum.

Comment: And what is the testcase? Please, share.

Comment: If you change `sumss=div3+div5-div15` to `sumss=div3+div5` it will fix your issue.

Comment: @Gi0rgi0s: I think the problem statement above is a bit confusing. I think the OP wants to solve project Euler #1.